# Topshelf Windows Service stops running overnight

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I have created a Windows Service using Topshelf that is meant to run on a fixed schedule and continue running every day. I am able to install the service and when I start it, it will run correctly during that day.

The problem that I encounter is that at the end of each day, the service stops polling. It no longer writes out to the log to indicate that the service is running or that the timer is tracking. Windows still lists this service as running, with the option to either stop or restart. I can manually restart the service which will let the service run until the end of the day. However, once the day ends and a new day begins, the service no longer seems to be running.

I have made some attempts to modify the settings for this service with no success. Is there a configuration value that needs to be set in order to let the service keep running without the need for a manual restart every day?

This is the relevant code for program.cs:

```
namespace MyService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                HostFactory.Run(x =>
                {
                    x.Service<ServiceManager>(s =>
                    {
                        s.ConstructUsing(FileProcess => new ServiceManager());
                        s.WhenStarted(FileProcess => FileProcess.Start());
                        s.WhenStopped(FileProcess => FileProcess.Stop());
                    });

                    x.StartAutomatically();

                    x.RunAsLocalSystem();

                    x.EnableServiceRecovery(recoverOption =>
                        {
                            recoverOption.RestartService(1);
                            recoverOption.RestartService(5);
                            recoverOption.TakeNoAction();
                        });

                        x.SetServiceName("MyService");
                        x.SetDisplayName("MyService v1.0");
                        x.SetDescription("This is the description for MyService.");
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the relevant code for ServiceManager.cs:

```
namespace MyService
{
    public class ServiceManager
    {
        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public ServiceManager()
        {    

            logger.Info("Service manager start");

            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

            //Converts TimerInterval from app.config into minutes. Timer elapses every (TimerInterval) minutes.
            Double timerInterval = (Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerInterval"]) * 1000 * 60);

            _timer = new Timer(timerInterval) { AutoReset = true };
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

            logger.Info("Service manager end");
        }

        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {                
                TaskManager tm = new TaskManager();
                tm.Run();                
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            logger.Debug("Start service");
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            logger.Debug("Stop service");
            _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the event log of the server to see if the service has failed three times in a row. Also please check this, it seems relevant: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/pull/481